# 'npm require' causes promise to not resolve

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, promise, electron

I'm writing an Electron app that communicates with a device via the adbkit module, and also needs to parse an x509 cert.  I have a function that gets called when the page loads to populate a field with information about the device.  The function can also be called by the user with a button.

After doing some work on it yesterday I noticed that when the page loaded it would no longer be populated with the device information, and instead I would have to click the button, in which case the function would execute normally.

After a lot of debugging, what I realized was that I had added `var x509 = require('x509.js')` at the top of a different script (request.js) included by the same html file so I could do the x509 parsing, and by doing that for some reason it appeared that the Promise returned by adbkit `listDevices()` in `devices.js` just never resolved.  The `.catch()` didn't catch anything, the `.finally()` never executed, it would just skip over the whole thing.

Then, if I simply comment out or move the `require` of x509.js down lower in request.js, inside the function which does the x509 parsing then `getDevices()` would execute as expected.

request.js:

```
var x509 = require('x509.js')
...various stuff

function parseCert () {
   <------- if I move 'var x509 = require('x509.js') here everything works fine
   ...do the cert parsing
}
```

devices.js:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird')
var adb = require('adbkit')
var client = adb.createClient()

function getDevices() {
    client.listDevices() <------ THIS PROMISE APPEARS TO NEVER RESOLVE 
                                 UNLESS THE BUTTON IS CLICKED OR X509 MOVED
      .then(function(devices) {
        return Promise.map(devices, function(device) {
          return client.shell(device.id, 'echo $RANDOM')
            // Use the readAll() utility to read all the content without
            // having to deal with the events. `output` will be a Buffer
            // containing all the output.
            .then(adb.util.readAll)
            .then(function(output) {
              console.log('[%s] %s', device.id, output.toString().trim())
            })
        })
      })
      .then(function() {
        console.log('Done.')
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.error('Something went wrong:', err.stack)
      })
      .finally(function() {
        console.log('hi mom')
      })
}
```

and finally index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
 ....
</head>

<body>
  <script src="./devices.js"></script>
  <script src="./request.js"></script>
  <script>getDevices()></script>
  ...
  <button onclick="getDevices()">Detect devices</button>
</body>
</html>
```

These are simplified, but I replaced my custom `getDevices()` function with the example from the adbkit documentation shown here and it behaved the same way, the promise returned by `client.listDevices()` appeared to just never resolve.  Then when I removed `var x509 = require('x509.js')` from request.js, it worked as expected.

Does this make any sense?  Is there such a thing as a buggy npm module?  Is there some kind of fundamental problem with my approach?  I'm planning on doing a lot of work with this framework and I hate not understanding this kind of behavior since I expect it to only get more complex from here.

Comment: how is `parseCert` relevant to the question? it's not called anywhere

Comment: Not that it answers your question, but you should not use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), since that is a JavaScript Constructor already.

Comment: @Jaromanda X: Just showing that if I move var x509 = require('x509.js') there then things work as expected.  That function is the only thing that needs the x509 module so I figured by moving the require there I could avoid whatever wierdness was happening by having it require it whenever the page loaded and in fact that seemed to fix it.

Comment: @PHPglue that's just boilerplate from the adbkit documentation: https://github.com/openstf/adbkit.  I guess I would assume they knew what they're doing but like I said I'm new to javascript.  You think that could be an issue?

Comment: I am suspecting x509 module is native node module with gyp - is that module actually correctly loaded in context of html's topmost script? can you verify those?

Comment: @OJKwon When you ask if I can verify that the module loaded correctly, I can parse the x509 certificate so I'm assuming it is correctly loaded.  It's this module:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/x509.js, not the native one with gyp

Comment: well so that's not a native indeed, and it is _asm.js_ module based on native codes - it makes bit difficult to guess what's going on. best shot is check asm.js module calls oninitialized correctly, then check asm module context is correctly setup on globals. It may worth to try inject custom oninit hook, but that'll only work if asmjs built with MODULARIZED. best guess is asmjs module is usually async init, some calls might need to wait for it (but this is based on my experience with other modules, so you need to confirm with x509)